# The game has a countless number of rounds

Tags: order-theory

Bob and Alice are going to play a math game. The game has a countless number of rounds. In the nth round.

Boba chooses a family $ F_n $ dfe rational open ranges (ie: data $ p, q \in \mathbb{Q}$, the range is the set $\left\{x \in \mathbb{Q} | p <x <q \right \}$ such that

$$\mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{I \in F_n } I$$.

We say that this family $F_n$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Alice chooses an $I_n \in F_n$ range

Alice wins the game if $\bigcup_ {n=1} ^ {\infty} I_n = \mathbb{Q}$, and Bob wins if he prevents Alice from winning. Display a winning strategy for Alice.

Attempt:
Let $r_1 < r_2 < r_3$ be a well ordering of the rational numbers. Then in round $n$, Alice should choose an interval that contains $r_n$. This will guarantee that she covers $\mathbb{Q}$ in a countably infinite number of rounds

I don't think it needs to be ordered, but why?

What if the families Bob chooses are not intervals but arbitrary unions or finite intersections of intervals?

Comment: If the game has an uncountable number of rounds, what does "the $n^{th}$ round" mean?

Comment: @lulu  I think the right property is that the rational numbers are countable.

Comment: Your post says, twice, that the number of rounds is "countless".  I think that you meant to just say that there were countably infinitely many rounds.  Also, I am guessing that you mean to say that, at each round, $A$ chooses one of the sets in $B's$ covering?  What you have written is really not clear.

Comment: @lulu That's exactly what you said, sorry for my mistake

Comment: If what I said is what you intended, then I don't see where order comes into the picture.  Just take any counting of the rationals, $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and then $A$ should make sure $x_n$ is covered by the choice in the $n^{th}$ round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have to be well-ordered, but that is a side property of what you need. Simply choosing a well-ordering of the rationals will not guarantee Alice a win. She needs an enumeration, as you have implicitly assumed and lulu has also mentioned.

By enumerating the rationals $\Bbb Q = \{r_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N}$, you have well-ordered it, namely with the order $r_i \prec r_j \iff i < j$. So a well-ordering in necessary.

But it is not sufficient. If Alice chooses an enumeration $\{q_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N}$ of $\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ and similarly defines $q_i \prec q_j \iff i < j$, and then continues to define $q_i \prec 0$ for all $i$, this also provides a well-ordering of $\Bbb Q$, but one in which Alice can theoretically lose, as she and Bob are not required to make another pick after doing infinitely many, and thus she may not ever pick a set containing $0$.

---

As for your other question, it does not matter what form the sets take. All that is required is that at each step Bob's family covers all of $\Bbb Q$ so that Alice can pick a set holding her required rational.

Comment: But you can't do this ordered...

Comment: If $ a, b \in \mathbb {Q} $, $ \frac {a + b} {2} \in \mathbb {Q} $. So there are rational infinities between $ q_n $ and $ q_ {n + 1} $ that didn't get

Comment: @Sullo - There is MORE than one way to order the rational numbers (or any set). The orderings I defined are NOT the normal $<$ of $\Bbb Q$. This is why I even chose a different symbol $\prec$ to represent them. You are the one who called $r_1 < r_2 < r_3$ a "well-ordering" in your post. If you meant $<$ to be the normal ordering, then that makes no sense, as the normal ordering does *not* well-order $\Bbb Q$, and you cannot simply demand it be so.